# Remove user/group from everyone group SharePoint online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions, security, groups

Is there a way to exclude a user or group from the 'everyone' security group in SP Online?

The reason I ask is we have blog site which everyone needs to be able to contribute to, simple - but we also a shared login account for around 300 users, we don't want them blogging/commenting on our blog site as they could say anything but we need them to be able to access the site and read the content. Adding all users to a security group and just excluding this shared account is not really feasible in my eyes due to the admin burden, then the on-going admin burden etc.. If anyone has any pointers it would be appreciated.
Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

The best suited way of addressing your scenario will be as follows:

1. Change the permissions of "everyone" to **read** only to the site so every one can be able to view the content.
2. Create a new AD security group with all the required 300 users (one time activity at  AD level) with out that shared login account.
3. Now add the new AD security group to the sharepoint site with **contribute** access.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add the shared account to a group and check if current user is in that group.
   If false continue loading the page
   Else throw an alert or block.
2. Or simply hardcode that the shared account details like it's email id
   Compare current user properties(which will have an email id) with the hardcoded values
   Then block or allow the user/group.

Hope this helps